# jQuery drop down - accordion

Tags: jquery

I am creating vertical navigation menu like accordion effect.

1. On click on either "nav-list--item a", it have to add class name "selected" to "h5" and slidedown to open submenu.
2. Other than selected menu, all other submenu or already opened submenu have to slideup.

How can I solve this issue? Below is the code I used.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-list--item">
  <h5><a href="javascript:void(0);" title=""><img src="images/svg/ts.svg" alt="" /><span>Item1</span></a></h5>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="">Calendar1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Calendar2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-list--item">
  <h5><a href="javascript:void(0);" title=""><img src="images/svg/ts.svg" alt="" /><span>Item2</span></a></h5>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="">Calendar3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Calendar4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.nav-list--item').on('click', function(){
  $('.nav-list--item h5.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $('.nav-list--item ul.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('h5').addClass('selected');
  $(this).find('ul').addClass('selected');

  if ($('.nav-list--item ul').hasClass('selected')){
    $('ul',this).slideDown();
  }
  else{
    $('ul', this).slideUp();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav-list--item').on('click', function(){
  $('.nav-list--item h5.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $('.nav-list--item ul.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('h5').addClass('selected');
  $(this).find('ul').addClass('selected');

  if ($('ul.submenu--item').is(':visible')) {
    $('ul.submenu--item').slideUp('slow');
  }

  if ($('> ul.submenu--item',this).length > 0) {
    $('> ul.submenu--item',this).stop().slideDown('slow');
  }
});
```